# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Current jQuery Being used**

```
$("#like_button").live("click", function(){
    var status = $(this).data("status");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var count = $(this).html();

        if(status === 1){
            like(id);
            $(this).removeClass("likes");
            $(this).addClass("liked");
            count++;
            $(this).html(count);
        }elseif(status === 2){
            like(id);
            $(this).removeClass("liked");
            $(this).addClass("likes");
            count--;
            $(this).html(count);
        }   else   {
            // do nothing
        }

        return false;

});
```

**The Error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { (Line 529)
```

Which is this line below,

```
}elseif(status === 2){
```

If you need anymore information to help me with this please be sure to ask.

Comment: there's a space between else and if.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript uses `else if` , not `elseif`.

Answer (score 1):

Read this tutorial to learn more about if else statements http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
}elseif(status === 2){
```

has to be

```
 }else if(status === 2){
```

Missing a space between **else** and **if**